# Seleção após clique

Tags: materialize

Estou usando a biblioteca materialize e quero implementar a seleção de um link após clicar nele em um menu lateral, side-nave, drop-down , estou tentando passar como parâmetro para a página a classe active, mas parece não funcionar neste caso, segue meu código:

```html
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav grey darken-4 fixed">
 <li><a class="white-text center-align" href="">Página Central</a></li>
 <li><a class="white-text" href="">Financeiro</a></li> 
 <li><a class="white-text" href="">Alunos</a></li>
 <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion active">  
  <li>
   <a class="white-text collapsible-header">Professores<i class="material-icons white-text right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
   <div class="collapsible-body grey darken-4">
           <ul>
             <li><a class="white-text" href="lista-professores.php">Listar Professores</a></li>
             <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Cadastrar Professores</a></li>
             <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Grade de aulas Professores</a></li>             
           </ul>
         </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```